# Photoshop changes colors when moved to a different monitor

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color-profiles

[This Yahoo! answers question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120724205258AAJQ3jG) pretty much sums up my predicament. Unfortunately I haven't really found an actual answer. Here's a screen shot of what happens when I place Photoshop between my monitors. Imagine that the left side of my laptop is the right square and the yellow is the right side of my monitor. When I move the program to one side fully or the other, it takes on the corresponding color.

Obviously the color on the right is correct and Photoshop is changing the color of the image when it moves to my external monitor. Also notice how none of the tools or anything are different colors, just the actual image itself.

**How do I fix this?**

**EDIT**

You may also notice that the color palette in the left corner is showing that yellow tinge. I didn't actually pick that yellow color, it's supposed to be showing the grey on the left that I used to fill in the square.

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: Weird that it happens only with the image. Probably won't help, but are both monitors color calibrated properly?

Comment: @Karan it only happens in photoshop and only to the file I'm working on. My monitor looks fine otherwise

Comment: Are you sure both monitors are set to have the same [color depth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_depth)?  Perhaps one of them is set to only 8, or 16 bit color, compared to the 24, or 32 probably used for your primary display.

Comment: @Zoredache both monitors are set at 32-bit truecolor. also, my monitor is a relatively new [AOC F22](http://us.aoc.com/monitor_displays/f22). My laptop is a fairly top-of-the-line ASUS gaming rig.

Comment: @Karan here's another weird thing: when I drag the image from the laptop to the monitor, the colors are correct *until I release the program*. once I release the drag over to the monitor, the colors change. this leads me to believe it's a Photoshop issue and not a monitor issue :\

Comment: I'm not really sure what's happening here TBH. Have you tried posting on the Photoshop Community forum as well? If this is a bug in the app then it might be impossible to work around and an official fix would be required from Adobe. (Edit: You might want to include details about the graphics card/driver as well in the question, in case someone wants to test.)

Comment: Where's the photoshop community? i looked for a stack exchange but i couldn't find one :\

Comment: Have you looked at the "Proof" settings? That is supposed to replicate the output of printers, there might be a secondary monitor setting there that is doing things..

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking here. People shouldn't have to follow a link to an external site just to find out what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon this question since I had the same issue. The question might be 2 years old by now but maybe there are others who struggle with this.

The solution for me was hidden in the settings of Photoshop.

Go to "Edit"->"Color Settings" and change the Settings to "Monitor Color". For me it was set to "North America General Purpose 2". After changing it to "Monitor Color", I then had the same colors on both my monitors finally.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled across this question and the Edit>Color Settings did not resolve the issue for me.

I ended up switching which monitor was the main display back and forth and that resolved the issue for me.

So Display 1 was my main display and i switched it to Display 2 then switched it back to Display 1 and now the image does not shift colors in Photoshop.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because of that you haven't calibrated your display and that it appears to be a "standard gamut" monitor means you're probably okay with having your system work at Windows default settings.

- Click Start, type color in the search box, then click **Color Management** when it comes up.
- In the Devices tab, ensure that your monitor is selected in the Device field.
- Check the **[ ] Use my settings for this device** box if it is not already checked.
- If the sRGB IEC61966-2.1 profile is not showing in the Profiles associated with this device box, hit the [Add...] button and add it.
- Click on **sRGB IEC61966-2.1** and choose **[Set as Default Profile]**.
- [Close]
- Now see if your colors look better in Photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

Almost 7 years later, and I'm encountering the same issue as the OP - on CC 2019, MacOS High Sierra.

I tried a hybrid approach, modifying both Photoshop and system color settings.

First, in PS: Edit > Color Settings - change RGB to "Monitor RGB" (mine showed as "Monitor RGB - HD 709-A").

Then I went into System Preferences > Displays > Color and switched to sRGB IEC61966-2.1.

Essentially I'm telling PS to adhere to system color settings (Monitor RGB) and setting ALL of my monitors to the same color profile. I chose sRGB because it's a more limited set of colors that will display fairly consistently across a variety of devices - something to consider when designing for web.